# Jboss tools doesn't publish my jar project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jboss6.x, jboss-tools

I have a problem with my eclipse (3.6, Helios) and my jboss tools plugin (3.2).

When I publish my war project with JbossTools in a jboss server, all jars in build path are publish in WEB-INF/lib directory on the server. It's ok for that.
But, I have several jar projects in eclipse linked to my war project. In the build path of my war project, these jars appear in the "Projects" tab, no in the "Libraries" tab. This works is normal but all projects in "Projects" tab are not publish in the server.

Someone can help me about that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For jar/wars you use the deployment/module assembly page in project properties.